# Json issue in getting date in golang dropbox library

Tags: go, dropbox-api

I'm writing a little program using the dropbox api to learn go. I'm using the client library here: https://github.com/stacktic/dropbox.

I'm able to upload and download a file so I know my api keys and what not are working correctly. Using the Metadata method I can get the metadata for a file. However, when I try to use the [UnmarshalJSON](https://godoc.org/github.com/stacktic/dropbox#DBTime.UnmarshalJSON) method to get a human readable date from the ClientMtime item in the entry struct, I get "unexpected end of JSON input". Any ideas on what's the issue?

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
func main() {

  db := dropbox.NewDropbox()
  db.SetAppInfo("Blah", "blah")
  db.SetAccessToken("Token")
  list,err := db.Metadata("/app_folder/test.jpg", true, false, "", "", 1)

  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  var date []byte
  err = list.ClientMtime.UnmarshalJSON(date)

  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  fmt.Printf("%v", date)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Go is usually really helpful in it's error messages so I am going go guess you have malformed Json.   Is the output of list valid json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
date, err := list.ClientMtime.MarshalJSON()
```

`UnmarshalJson` goes the other way; `[]byte -> DBTime` 
That's why it's an end of input error, the `[]byte` is empty.

Optionally, `ClientMTime` is a time. Time which has `String()` and `Format()` methods.

You can access all the time formatting features by converting it.

See: https://github.com/stacktic/dropbox/blob/master/dropbox.go#L158

Comment: That was it. Thanks!